# How do I correctly format putting an "if" in python

Tags: python, authentication, console

How would I put "if" or "else" in code like this?

```
user = input('Login: Username\n')
time.sleep(1)
password = input('Login: Password\n')
print('Welcome, %s.' % user)
```

Comment: Always use something like `getpass.getpass` for entering passwords.

Comment: If more code is needed I will provide more.

Comment: What do you mean? *"how would I put 'if' or 'else' in code like this?"* ??? - just type it in the script? You should really clarify your question.

Comment: @Mydnyte not very clear what you are saying provide the full code or more information. Thanks

Comment: Your `if` and `else` statements are conditions.  So what conditions would you like to check? This is incredibly vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do. But this is not a secure way of doing password requests.

```py
user = input('Login: Username\n')
password = input('Login: Password\n')

users = {"You" : "1234", "Me" : "abcd"}

if user in users.keys():
    if users[user] == password:
        print("Welcome, {u}".format(u=user))
    else:
        print("Wrong password")
    
else:
    print("This user does not exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version on how this should work but is not secure at all, but functions (almost) the same way as you requested  (came up with this under 5 mins)

```
user = input('Login Username: ')
password = input('Login Password: ')
  if user == ("Your username here"):
    if password == ("Your password here"):
      print("Welcome ", user)
```

Also you do not need "time.sleep()" as it only slows down your code